# pyQt5 AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'txtCustCode'

Tags: python, boolean, attributeerror

Using QT Designer to design the code. Then using the `pyuic5 -x productentryscreen.ui > productentryscreen3.py` command to generate python code.
i am using buttons and textboxes. when a button is pressed i want to display value entered in the QlineEdit box. 
But i am getting the error " AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute"  when the btnCancel is clicked. This is where the error is thrown (i presume) `textboxValue = self.txtCustCode.text`. i even tried with `textboxValue = self.txtCustCode.text()`
Following is the code

```
   import sqlite3
   from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
   from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject
   from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
   from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
   from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QAction, QLineEdit, 
   QMessageBox

   # Generated Code
    class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    #def setupUi(self):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 130, 160, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 160, 130, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 190, 120, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 220, 180, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 240, 170, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 30, 481, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_6.setFont(font)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.txtHMI = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.txtHMI.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 130, 211, 20))
        self.txtHMI.setObjectName("txtHMI")
        self.txtCustCode = QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.txtCustCode.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 160, 211, 20))
        self.txtCustCode.setObjectName("txtCustCode")
        self.txtProdCode = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.txtProdCode.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 190, 211, 20))
        self.txtProdCode.setObjectName("txtProdCode")
        self.txtCustPartNo = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.txtCustPartNo.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 220, 211, 20))
        self.txtCustPartNo.setObjectName("txtCustPartNo")
        self.txtLampName = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.txtLampName.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 250, 211, 20))
        self.txtLampName.setObjectName("txtLampName")
        self.btnSave = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btnSave.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 280, 131, 41))
        self.btnSave.setObjectName("btnSave")
        self.btnSave.clicked.connect(btnSave_click)

        self.btnCancel = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btnCancel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 280, 131, 41))
        self.btnCancel.setObjectName("btnCancel")
        self.btnCancel.clicked.connect(btnCancel_click)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
          _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
          MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
          self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Product as in HMI"))
          self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Customer Code"))
          self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Product Code"))
          self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Customer Part Number"))
          self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Lamp Name & Type"))
          self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Products Data Entry / Update Screen"))
          self.btnSave.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SAVE"))
          self.btnCancel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Cancel"))

    # End Generated Code

    @pyqtSlot() # Signals buttons

    def btnCancel_click(self):
    textboxValue = "Dummy"
    textboxValue = self.txtCustCode.text
    #QMessageBox.question(self, 'Message - pythonspot.com', "You typed: " + textboxValue, QMessageBox.Ok, QMessageBox.Ok)
    print (textboxValue)
    cancelFunction()
def btnSave_click(self):
    print ("Save Clicked")
    insertFunction()

# Functions for signals
def insertFunction():
    print ("Save Clicked")

def cancelFunction():
    print ("Cancel  Clicked")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

**Below line returns a boolean value.**

```
self.txtCustCode = QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
```

Then you are trying to using `setGeometry` attribute. That's why it gives you error.

```
self.txtCustCode.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 160, 211, 20))
self.txtCustCode.setObjectName("txtCustCode")
```

Comment: I have already tried removing the centralwidget and setGeometry. yet I am getting the same issue. Can you please post the replacement code . thanks

Comment: If possible then try to put debug point on that line and check response of  `self.txtCustCode = QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)` this line.
It is possible that `QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)` returns always boolean value. That's why it is giving you an error.

Comment: `self.setWindowTitle("Product Entry Screen") 
        self.txtHMI =QLineEdit(self)
        self.txtHMI.move(230, 130)
        self.txtHMI.resize(211, 20)
        self.txtHMI.setObjectName("txtHMI")
        self.txtCustCode = QLineEdit(self)
        self.txtCustCode.move(230, 160)
        self.txtCustCode.resize(211, 20)    
        self.btnCancel =QPushButton(self)
        self.btnCancel.move(330, 280)
        self.btnCancel.resize(131, 41)  
        self.btnCancel.setObjectName("btnCancel")
        self.btnCancel.clicked.connect(btnCancel_click)`

Comment: I have removed the centralwidget from above code. Still same issue